# Правильное закрытие сервера Express + сохранение файла

Tags: node.js, express

У меня в проекте используется Express, я хочу понять, как правильно закрывать сервер (после нажатия ctrl+c) ибо иногда я не могу запустить заново, пишет, что порт занят и приходится закрывать редактор. А иногда сервер выключается через секунд 30 после ctrl+c.

Так же я хочу узнать, как при ctrl+c мне сохранить конфиг в файл, на данный момент сделано, как в приложенном коде, но получилось один раз, что в файл записалось {}, стандартное значение config, то есть оно похоже очистило переменную до сохранения.
Сейчас у меня что-то типо этого, но я не уверен в правильности и думаю, что это делается по другому.

```
process.on('exit', () =>
{
    saveConfig.bind(config);
});
process.on('SIGUSR1', () =>
{
    saveConfig.bind(config);
});
process.on('SIGUSR2', () =>
{
    saveConfig.bind(config);
});
process.on('uncaughtException', () =>
{
    saveConfig.bind(config);
});
process.on('SIGINT', () =>
{
    saveConfig(config);
    server.close(() =>
    {
        console.log(`process.on('SIGINT'): server.close(): Server closed!`);
        process.exit(-1);
    });
});
```

Comment: Мне непонятен смысл вызова bind

Comment: Скорее всего я указывал saveConfig как callback, а затем решил вынести в стрелочную функцию, чтобы добавить консоль лог, и забыл/забил изменить.

Comment: Просто `saveConfig.bind(config)` не вызывает `saveConfig`, а только привязывает this, но и это бессмысленно, т.к. результат привязки никуда не сохраняется. Т.е. ваши первых 4 обработчика сигналов не делают вообще ничего.

Comment: Обработчик SIGINT выглядит рабочим. Может вы словили сигнал до того, как в config появились какие-то данные?

Comment: От первых 4 обработчиков вообще есть смысл, если правильно вызвать функцию? Данная проблема была не у меня, а у человека который тестил и он конечно же не запомнил что и как. Как это могло произойти и как избежать в дальнейшем?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В зависимости от разновидностей ОС сигналы прерывания процессового потока могут отличаться характерностью этих ОС. Что касается `UNIX` подобных систем, вы можете обрабатывать сигналы `SIGTERM` и `SIGINT`, как описано в [документации](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_signal_events) `NodeJS`.

При нажатии комбинаций клавишь `CTRL` + `C`, [POSIX](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX) [ [2](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) ] отправляет программе сигнал `SIGINT` "**Interrupt from keyboard**" (Прерывание с клавиатуры).

При повторном нажатии комбинаций клавишь `CTRL` + `C`, `POSIX` уже знает что ранее уже был вызван сигнал `SIGINT` и на этот раз сопутствующим сигналом посылается сигнал `SIGTERM` **Termination signal** (Сигнал завершения).

Для того чтобы правильно обрабатывать эти сигналы, на них нужно повесить обработчики. Вернемся в документацию `NodeJS` и посмотрим что там сказано:

> «SIGTERM» и «SIGINT» имеют обработчики по умолчанию на платформах,
> отличных от Windows, которые сбрасывают режим терминала перед выходом
> с кодом 128 + номер сигнала. Если у одного из этих сигналов установлен
> слушатель, его поведение по умолчанию будет удалено (Node.js больше не
> будет выходить).

Конечно он будет выходить, если вы правильно напишете обработчик завершения потокового процесса.

Если при повторном запуске сервера (предполагается что перед данным запуском было завершение программы посредством клавиш `CTRL` + `C`), вероятнее всего предыдущий процесс выполнения был неправильно обработан/завершен и в результате процесс продолжает свою работу в фоновом режиме, не смотря на то что была попытка прервать сеанс. Поэтому вы видите сообщение о том, что порт занят.

Что же нам необходимо для правильного завершения нашего процесса? Некоторые разработчики прибегают к одному из таких решений:

```
process.on("SIGINT", () => process.exit(0));
process.on("SIGTERM", () => process.exit(0));
```

Это грубое завершение процесса и оно не совсем подходит если у вас в потоке процесса находятся еще несколько задач, которые необходимо правильно завершить и вывести отчет о работе всей программы.

Как это сделать? Давайте подумаем что такое `Express`? На самом деле это обычный фреймворк под копотом у которого родные механизмы `NodeJS`. Когда мы создаем очередной сервер и вызываем [app.listen()](http://expressjs.com/ru/api.html#app.listen), `Express` запускает родной мехнизм обработки `NodeJS` сервера [http.Server.listen()](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_server_listen) модуля [http](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html) и в качестве возвращаемого результата отдает инстанс на этот сервер.

```
let server;
server = app.listen(3000, "127.0.0.1", () => {
  process.stdout.write("listening\n"));
}
```

Идем в документацию и смотрим что возвращает метод `listen()`, а возвращает он экземпляр [net.Server](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_class_net_server), соответственно смотрим его интерфейс и находим там метод [close](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_server_close_callback), который завершает поток процесса нашего ранее созданного сервера посредством выражения `app.listen()`.

Таким образом, для правильного завершения, нам всего лишь необходимо закрыть наш сервер, вот таким образом:

```
server.close();
```

А теперь напишем наш скрипт:

```
const fs = require("fs");
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

let ctrlcPressed = 0;
let timer;
let server;

function saveConfig(filepath, data, cb) {
  fs.writeFileSync(filepath, data, { encoding: "utf-8" });
  cb && cb();
}

function onInterrupt() {
  if (ctrlcPressed === 0) {
    timer = setTimeout(() => {
      process.stdout.write("Press again to exit\n");
    }, 200);
  }
  ctrlcPressed++;
}

function onTerminate() {
  clearTimeout(timer);

  const configData = "config data\n";
  saveConfig("config.cfg", configData, () => {
    server.listening && server.close((err) => {
      if (err) {
        process.stderr.write(`${err.message}\n`);
        process.exit(-1);
      }
    });

    // этот вызов не обязателен
    // process.exit(0);
  });
}

// Вы также можете предварительно удалить все обработчики,
// но это не обязательно.
// Наличие новых обработчиков должно перезаписать старые.
// process.removeAllListeners("SIGTERM");
// process.removeAllListeners("SIGINT");

process.on("SIGINT", onInterrupt);
process.on("SIGTERM", onTerminate);
process.on("exit", function () {
  process.stdout.write("exit\n");
});

app.get("/", function (req, res) {
  res.send("hello world");
});

server = app.listen(3000, "127.0.0.1", () => {
  process.stdout.write("listening\n"));
}
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо за проделанную работу. Все очень доходчиво и понятно. Мог бы как-то отметить ответ полезным несколько раз - сделал бы (не нарушая правила).